# How to pass Activity type to a method in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android-activity, types, xamarin.android, parameter-passing

All my activities inherit from `BaseActivity`. In `BaseActivity` I have the following method:

```
protected void GoToPreviousActivity(Activity)
{
    StartActivity(typeof(Activity));
    Finish();
}
```

When I click the `toolbar's` back button of every activity I want to go back to the previous activity, like that:

```
toolbar.NavigationOnClick += delegate
{
    this.GoToPreviousActivity(PreviousActivity);
};
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So you wanna "fake" the activity backstack?

Comment: I don't know what "fake the activity backstack" means. I just don't want to repeat `GoToPreviousActivity` method definition in every activity.

Comment: Okay, perhaps this helps... 1. Whenever you go to an activity, use the StartActivity, and by default you will have a stack of activities... 2. When you then Finish() the top activity (the one you are shown), it is being discarded and the previous activity will be shown...3. If you want to go to a specific activity in your stack, you could apply the ClearTop, which finishes all activities above the activity type you want to navigate to (and if it does not exists in your stack, it will be added (like normally starting an activity)... Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  @Mathias Kirkegaard commented, Android provides its own navigation back and it is very reliable (you can even manipulate the back stack (see the link at the bottom about what is it))

Having said that, if you want to use your method every time the user clicks on the back button you can override the OnBackPressed method, and provide your own implementation there.
In your case:

```
 public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        //base.OnBackPressed(); <-- this will use the default behaviour to navigate back, and if I understood correctly, you don't want to use it
        GoToPreviousActivity(PreviousActivity);
    }
```

Even though you can do that and it is valid, it is discouraged, you can read more about how Android manages the back navigation here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

and here is a good article on how to implement a custom back navigation: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

Answer (score 1):

should use OnBackPressed methode on click

```
base.OnBackPressed();
```